# How to make a Javascript fade sliding background?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on some final schoolyears project, but I keep-on messing with the image slider I want to use as a background.

It's working, but there ain't no special effect that makes is fadeIn slowly.

Can you suggest a solution for my problem?

My code so far:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
    var images = new Array();
    images[0] = "img/bck.png";
    images[1] = "img/bck2.png";
    images[2] = "img/bck3.png";
    images[3] = "img/bck4.png";
    images[4] = "img/bck5.png";

    window.onload = function showDelay() {
        setInterval ("changeBg()", 3000);
    }

    var i=0;
    function changeBg() {
        if (i==5) {
            i=0;
        }
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+images[i]+')';
        i++;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: why is your `changeBg()` function on `""`?

Comment: JQyery has support for fadeIn and fadeOut. Works like a charm

Comment: Two things, first: don't use `new Array()`, use an array-literal (`images = ['img/bck.png','img/bck2.png'/* and so on*/]`); and second: don't pass a function as a string to `setInterval()`, pass a function.

Comment: @cr0ss It's because it didn't work without the ""

Comment: @TGH I searched for the JQuery script like that, but didn't work out well

Comment: @DavidThomas Can you please help me with passing that function?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the same by using jQuery.

**Working Example -** http://codepen.io/nitishdhar/pen/fhjkD

**Code Setup & Explanation**

Setup your HTML like this -

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="bg-holder">
   <img class="fade" src="http://placehold.it/940x800/DF013A">
   <img class="fade" src="http://placehold.it/940x800/A901DB">
   <img class="fade" src="http://placehold.it/940x800/013ADF">
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Have create a div which holds all your background images that you want to use.

Add some CSS -

```
.bg-holder {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  background-color: #000;
}
.bg-holder img.fade {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Then add some jQuery code, don't forget to use include jQuery library in your head -

```
function setupBackgroundAnimation() {
  $('img.fade').hide();
  $('.bg-holder').css({ 'height': $(window).height(),'width': $(window).width() });
  animateBackground();
}

function animateBackground() {
  $(".bg-holder img.fade").first().appendTo('.bg-holder').fadeOut(1500);
  $(".bg-holder img").first().fadeIn(1500);
  setTimeout(animateBackground, 3000);
}

/*Initiate Animated Background on Document Ready*/
$(document).ready(function() {
   setupBackgroundAnimation();
});
```

The animateBackground function takes hold of the first image in the bg-holder div & moves it to the last while fading it out. It then brings the next image by fading it in. This is repeated every 3000 ms ( 1500 ms taken while fading the current image out & 1500 for fading in the next image)

setupBackgroundAnimation function resizes your bg-holder to fit the current window size.

Comment: what browser are you using? are you saying your implementation did not work or the codepen demo url is also not working?

Comment: @RikEckhardt - did it work? which browser are you using?

Comment: @RikEckhardt which browser are you using?

Answer (score -1):

```
!function( global, doc ){

 var images = ["img/bck.png", "img/bck2.png", "img/bck3.png" /* ... */ ]
  , i = 0;

 global['onload'] = function() {
  setInterval (function(){
    i === 5 && (i = 0);
     doc.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + images[i] + ')';
    i++;
    }, 3000);
  }

 }(window, document)
```

Comment: you should really explain what your code does. Just giving the OP some code (maybe works maybe doesn't) doesn't help them in the long run.